# Python basic math operations

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

So I'm trying to make a game which takes your level, multiplies it by 5, divides the product by 25, then multiplies that by 100, to get your attack variable. The code for default looks like below;

```
level = 1
atk = ((level * 5) / 25) * 100
```

Now, if following basic math, that would make ((1*5)/25)*100). That means the answer should be 20. Python, however, reports 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a little nit: "...multiplies it by 5, divides the product by 25..." is equivalent to multiplying by 1 and dividing by 5.

Comment: right, i knew that. i can basic math, don't mind me lmfao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the level as a real number so that the ark also will be a real,

> this is a python magic lol

level=1.0
atk=(level*5/25)*100
print atk